# Magento 2: How to Set controller, module, action name?

Tags: magento2, module, controllers, routing

I want to do these codes like in magento 1

```
$request->setModuleName('catalogsearch')
        ->setControllerName('advanced')
        ->setActionName('result');
```

and then the page load content page like catalogsearch/advanced/result/ page. but Url still keep old url like  /abc/xyz.html

Comment: Refer useful to you http://inchoo.net/magento-2/routing-in-magento-2/

Comment: What did you try? Where in the code do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm just done with this, but still need help
please check my new question...
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109922/magento-2-how-to-route-the-page-to-catalogsearch-advanced-result-page-with-abc

Answer (score 2):

try from controller

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
        $request->getModuleName('catalogsearch');
        $request->setControllerName('advanced');
        $request->setActionName('index');
```

Answer (score 2):

I just done with this

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        //get request object
$requestOb = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
$requestOb->setRouteName('catalogsearch')
    ->setControllerName('advanced')
    ->setActionName('result');
```