# Magento 2: How to route the page to catalogsearch/advanced/result/ page with abc/xyz.html Url

Tags: magento2, event-observer, catalogsearch, routing

I created an observer to catch the event when a new url is requested with

```
<event name="controller_front_send_response_before">
    <observer name="brands_index_events_observer" instance="WiserobotT\ManufacturerinfoT\Observer\BrandObserver" />
</event>
```

I check the Url if it matches `abc/xyz.html`, then set routeName, ControllerName and ActionName:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        //get request object
$requestOb = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
$requestOb->setRouteName('catalogsearch')
    ->setControllerName('advanced')
    ->setActionName('result');
```

I use `var_dump($requestOb->getFullActionName());`
and a get

```
string(29) `catalogsearch_advanced_result`
```

Good! But the page still shows: The page you requested was not found...

I want the page to have content like the `catalogsearch/advanced/result` page but still keep the old url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally to solved my problem. Thanks God. hahaha
after use this to set controllerName,RouteName, actionName, and params

`$request->setModuleName('catalogsearch')->setControllerName('advanced')->setActionName('result')->setParam('manufacturer', $_manu->getData('option_id'));`

a found an error with this code in controller `Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Advanced\Result`

`$this->_catalogSearchAdvanced->addFilters($this->getRequest()->getQueryValue());`
I rewrite this controller and fix this code to 
`$this->_catalogSearchAdvanced->addFilters($this->getRequest()->getParams());`
DONE. It's work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_front_send_response_before">
        <observer name="custom_controller_front_send_response_before" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\ResponseObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ResponseObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $objectManager = $this->objectManager;
        $requestObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
        $responseObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http');
        // check your condition here
        if($requestObj->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') {
            $url = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/index');
            $responseObj->setRedirect($url)
                ->sendResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!! but the url also change to new url, but a need to keep my own url

Comment: when catch enable than this not work in Magento2.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong event. When `controller_front_send_response_before` is triggered, the request object already has been processed and the complete response HTML (with "The page you requested was not found") generated.

You could use the `controller_action_predispatch` event instead. This also happens when the responsible controller already has been determined, but it's not executed yet and you can trigger the route matching again with:

```
$request->setDispatched(false);
```

Comment: Thank you so much with that event. It works but the page is mess up with 2 content, one from catalog and one from 404, the title is 404 page. When I put `$request->setDispatched(false);` I got error

`Error 503 Service Unavailable

Service Unavailable
Guru Meditation:

XID: 66280584

Varnish cache server`

Comment: I see, the problem is that the "noroute" action (404) behaves differently than others. The correct approach for your problem would be to create a custom router instead of using an observer. It is explained in detail here: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/routing-in-magento-2/

Comment: thank you, I think You just show me the right way, but I got error




`Front controller reached 100 router match iterations`




> when I try to catch in foreach loop:




`if(strpos($identifier, $brandprefix) !== false) {

foreach ($brandCollection as $key => $_manu) {
if(strpos($identifier, $_manu->getData('url_key')) !== false )
{
/*
* We must set module, controller path and action name for our controller class(Controller/Test/Test.php)
*/
$request->setModuleName('catalogsearch')->setControllerName('advanced')->setActionName('index');
}
}
}`